# Writing text to terminal with some period

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I'm new to python and programming. As I'm trying to gain experience, I thought I could make a terminal riddle game. It will be a simple question/answer game.

My approach is the following:
There is a .txt (contains riddles) file, which I open with the python program. I want to imitate typing in the terminal, so I'm using the time module pretty largely. Now, I have managed to imitate typing in the terminal, it types letters with one speed, without pause, but in some places I want the program to wait for 2 or 4 seconds before it will continue typing (for a more dramatic effect).

One solution that I was able to find is that I have placed symbols in the .txt file (for example, "p-2" indicates "pause for 2 seconds"). Text file looks like this:

```
What is Lorem Ipsum?
p-1
Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
p-2
```

Python file looks like this:

```
def text_output(message):
    for i in message:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        print(i, end='', flush=True)

if "p-1" in data:
    data = data.replace("p-1", "time.sleep(1)")

if "p-2" in data:
    data = data.replace("p-2", "time.sleep(2)")

if "p-4" in data:
    data = data.replace("p-4", "time.sleep(4)")

exec(data)
```

As you see, the code finds symbols in the text and replaces them with the python code, and then the exec() function executes this code. However, I do not like this approach, and I think there is a more convenient way to achieve this effect.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: would you please accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very interesting feature, I think. This is what I would do to generate sensible output after every line, word, character, ...

```
import time
import random
with open("/path/to/file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

def text_output(message, t):
    for i in message:
        time.sleep(t)
        print(i, end='', flush=True)

for num, line in enumerate(lines):
    if num == 1:
        time.sleep(random.randrange(4, 5))      # after title
    for word in line.split(" "):
        time.sleep(random.randrange(0.5, 2))    # after a word
        for character in word:
            text_output(character, random.randrange(0.05, 0.5))     # after a character
```

Comment: @nodargelovani would you please accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Hey. Sorry for late answer. Your approach is really interesting, however, it does not answers my problem. Thank you for you interest!